# SQL Query - Joining and Aggregating

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to run a query every hour against a table that joins and aggregates data from another table with millions of rows.

```
    select f.master_con, 
        s.containers 
    from 
        (
            select master_con 
            from shipped 
            where start_time >= a and start_time <= a+1
        ) f, 
        (
            select master_con, 
                 count(distinct container) as containers 
            from picked
        ) s
        where f.master_con = s.master_con
```

This query above sorta works, the exact syntax may not be correct because I wrote it from memory.

In the sub query 's' I only want to count container for each master_con in the 'f' query, and I think my query runs for a long time because I'm counting container for all master_con but then joining only to master_con from 'f'

Is there a better, more efficient way to write this type of query?

(In the end, I'll sum(containers) from this query above to get total containers shipped during that hour)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is. Can you provide some simplified sample table structures? Additionally, the join method being used has been moving towards deprecation for some time. You should declare your joins explicitly. The below should be an improvement. Left outer join was used so that you get all of the shipper records that meet your criteria and keep them even if they aren't in the picked table. Change that to inner join if you want them gone.

```
    SELECT shipped.master_con, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT picked.containers) AS containers
    FROM shipped LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Picked ON picked.master_con = shipped.master_con
    WHERE shipped.start_time BETWEEN a AND a+1
    GROUP BY shipped.master_con
```

Comment: Thanks for the join advice, I'll give this a whirl when I get into the office tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds good. If it doesn't do what you need, edit your OP and toss in a sample of each table with 4-5 rows and then an example of what you want your out to look like based off those two tables . Good luck